# how to replace hard data with a REDUX ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, get, react-redux, axios

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

To make a summary, currently, I have an app that allows you to order.

I use REDUX to pass information

currently the product I use works like this

```
const initState = {
    category:  [{id:1 ,name:'Bières'},{id:2 ,name:'Cocktails'}]-
    items: [
    {id:1,title:"Campus",ctg:1},
    {id:2,title:"Dark and Stormy",ctg:2},
     ],
     addedItems:[],
      total: 0
      }
```

then I do several ,full of action that adds and suppresses ( i can show if you want )

infact here i did no problem everything works fine.

and me my problem and the next one done I would like to be able to replace the data 
{ id : 1 title: " Campus", ctg:1 } by MY DATA on MY BDD

I would like to make a GET (axios or fetch no care ) instead of having hard data

How can I fix this issue?